# setup local informix db as in server

Tags: sql, database, informix, local

currently i'm working with informix db server which is not in local, where can't connect from outside office or virtual lan, so there is any tools so i can copy all table and work locally,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export database to text using `dbexport` and import it locally using `dbimport`. There are other way of migrating database, but for small databases it should work. The data is in text so it may be easy to change something (for example data format), or even use such export to import data to other database. Have a look at: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mig.doc/mig138.htm